# png image in pdf generated by TCPDF shows .. black background

Tags: php, png, tcpdf

I am developing a pdf using TCPDF . But when I try to print a PNG image the background of the image in pdf looks dark ..

Please help me .. If any one know about its solution

Regards

Comment: some code might be useful.....

Comment: Yes, some code definitely would be helpful. Also, does the PNG have a transparent background?

Comment: Yes the png have a transparent background. and am printing the image like                                                     $pdf->Image($image_path.$fetch_im->imid.'.jpg',$x_im+32.8,$y_im+32,$w_im,$h_im);

Comment: I believe there's also a bug flying around. I've 3 images into an svg included with `ImageSVG`, if the first image is a transparent png then the others have a black background, if the first is a jpeg the others display correctly (6.2.17)

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the transparency of the PNG. Possibly you are using alpha transparency in your png so please convert it to index transparency.

Answer (score 0):

TCPDF uses GD or ImageMagick (via Imagick) for image manipulation. There is also built-in image manipulation. So it's a complex topic.

I had a transparency issue using TCPDF with ImageMagick on Debian 9. As you described the transparent background was replaced by black color in pdf generated. I could fix the issue by installing `imagemagick-common` package additionally to `imagemagick-6.q16` and `php-imagick`.